# Why is mut required for fn param when variable defined with mut

Tags: rust

The following code works the way expected, however I'm hoping to find a good reason why the "mut" qualifier is required on the first parameter when calling the add_employee fn.

Since the variable emps is defined with mut, and the signature expects it, why is that not sufficient?

```
struct Employee {
        name: String,
        age: u16,
}
impl Employee {
    fn new() -> Employee {
        Employee {
            name: "Julia".to_string(),
            age: 15
        }
    }
}

fn add_employee(emps: &mut Vec<Employee>, emp: Employee) {
    emps.push(emp);
}

fn main() {
    let mut emps: Vec<Employee> = Vec::new();
    add_employee(&mut emps, Employee::new());   // why is mut required here?
    
    println!("name = {}, age = {}", emps[0].name, emps[0].age);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because mutability is an attribute of [variables](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html?highlight=mutable#variables-and-mutability) and [references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html?highlight=reference#mutable-references), not the data they're referring to. This is easier to see without the function call.

```
// emps is a mutable variable.
let mut emps: Vec<Employee> = Vec::new();

// this is fine, emps is being mutated.
emps.push(Employee { name: "First".to_string(), age: 42 });


// emps_ref is an immutable variable containing an immutable reference.
let emps_ref = &emps;

// this is an error, push() cannot mutate an immutable reference.
emps_ref.push(Employee { name: "Second".to_string(), age: 99 });
```

Instead to mutate the reference we need a mutable reference: `let emps_ref = &mut emps`. Similarly, the reference passed into add_employee must be mutable.

Note that the `emps_ref` variable is immutable, you can't assign to it again.

Comment: And this isn't just an academic distinction. Multiple *immutable* references can exist to *mutable* data and access it concurrently, but if one of those references is declared `&mut` then the others can't exist.

Comment: Thank you. The clarity of your answer was very helpful. Being a long time C/C++ programmer, but new to rust, my challenge was to see what your first sentence "Because mutability.." captures very well. It belongs in a book on rust. ( My apologies to any author who wrote something as clear and it went over my head at the time! )  i.e. that variables and references are what "carry" mutability. A related question that might call for another topic is how it must be the case that a mutable variable containing a structure passes it's mutability deeply into all the elements that make up the structure.